# define an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript.
I want to have an object with this structure.

```
Users = {
    User1 : {
        "name" : "name",
        "id"   : "123"
    }
    User2 : {
        "name" : "name",
        "id"   : "123"
    }
}
```

so I should define Users like this:

```
 var Users = {};
```

How can I add new User to `Users`? and How can I read and write from users inside `Users` object like this:

```
 // reading
 User1_name = Users.User1.name;

 // writing
 Users.User1.name = "new name";
```

Comment: What's the question? You code seems OK so far.

Comment: it's not a code, I want the code

Comment: It is pretty much valid code. Just, as mentioned, a comma is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* define users like this, you are just missing a comma

```
Users = {
    User1 : {
        "name" : "name",
        "id"   : "123"
    } <--
    User2 : {
        "name" : "name",
        "id"   : "123"
    }
}
```

Should be ( with var added for clarity )

```
var Users = {
    User1 : {
        "name" : "name",
        "id"   : "123"
    },
    User2 : {
        "name" : "name",
        "id"   : "123"
    }
}
```

Reading and writing can be done the way you described.

To add a new user, you could do something like this

```
Users["User3"] = {
    "name" : "name3",
    "id"   : "1234"
}
```

Comment: User3 comes from php, so it can be anything. is it valid to be `var username = 'somename' ` And `Users.username = { 'name' : 'name', 'id' : '123' }`  ?

Comment: `Users[username] =  { 'name' : 'name', 'id' : '123' }`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine (except the missing comma @Philipp pointed), but you can use an array too:

```
var users = [
    {
        "name" : "name",
        "id"   : "123"
    },
    {
        "name" : "name",
        "id"   : "123"
    }
];

var userName = users[0].name;

users[0].name = "new name";
```

Comment: +1 This is a better way to handle *users* in an easy enumerable way.